# Disabling DEP for an Outlook 2010 Add-In

Tags: vb6, outlook, add-in, dep

Is there any way to do this?

My legacy VB6 add-in utilizes a legacy (likely C++) third party component to make some UI "skin" enhancements.  It works fine in Outlook 2000-2007 but fails in 2010 due to DEP - and likely the manner in which my "skinning" component accesses memory.

If I disable DEP globally in Outlook (via the Trust Center) it works fine however this isn't a viable solution for my client.

I've tried adding my DLL to the DEP Opt-Out list in **System Properties > Performance > DEP** however it didn't seem to have any affect.  Nor did adding the "skinning" DLL, the MS VB6 virtual machine it runs under, or even Outlook.EXE to the list.

If anyone can point me in the right direction re: disabling JUST my add-in from DEP, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Outlook 2010 (if viewed using Process Explorer) seems to run with the DEP Permanent designation which - I believe - precludes it from exclusions.  I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't due to DEP, but the fact that they completely changed how to interact with Outlook 2010 compared to earlier versions.  They (being Microsoft), stated that while old code could still work... they do not guarantee smooth operation.